# How do I use lsquic (LiteSpeed QUIC and HTTP/3 library)?

Tags: quic

https://github.com/litespeedtech/lsquic
I want to implement lsquic. after the setup in the readme, what should I do to send data from client to server and track the network traffic? For setup, do I just follow the three steps, install BoringSSL, LSQUIC and then docker? Would just copy and paste the commands in Terminal work?
Error message:

```
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /src/lsquic/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /Users/nini/Development/lsquic/boringssl/lsquic where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /src/lsquic &&     cmake -DBORINGSSL_DIR=/src/boringssl . &&     make' returned a non-zero code: 1
(base) pc-68-32:lsquic nini$ sudo docker run -it --rm lsquic http_client -s www.google.com  -p / -o version=Q046
Password:
Unable to find image 'lsquic:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for lsquic, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: Feel free to open an issue on GitHub.  For example, @Peter opened a [Docker-related issues](https://github.com/litespeedtech/lsquic/issues/140) that may be relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build lsquic with docker and *then* run it (because of the "unable to find" error, i think you did not build the docker image). To do so, git clone (just) the lsquic repository, and run the commands given in the section titled "Building with Docker". The docker build will (o.a.) download boringssl and build it, so you don't have to do that yourself and then it will build lsquic for you.

Comment: and building lsquic fails on my machine with a compiler error ;-(

Comment: I think the developer said that they did not update the docker image for some time.

Comment: @Saige, please check today's release -- the Docker issue has been fixed.